# ReactiveUI - Multiple InvokeCommand is not working for a single observable

Tags: vb.net, winforms, reactiveui

My DetailsViewModel watches for changes in a selected EnvelopeViewModel and updates the AgendaItemId of the DetailsViewModel.

```
MessageBus.Current.Listen(Of EnvelopeViewModel) _
        .Where(Function(x) x IsNot Nothing) _
        .Select(Function(x) x.AgendaItemID) _
        .ToPropertyEx(Me, Function(vm) vm.AgendaItemId)
```

I update the DetailsViewModel using the AgendaItem returned from _agendaItemService. I believe this is causing issues.

```
UpdateViewModel = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(Function(x) _agendaItemService.FindAsync(AgendaItemId))
UpdateViewModel.SubscribeOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler).Subscribe(Sub(agendaItem) UpdateDetails(agendaItem))
UpdateViewModel.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(Sub(ex) Log.ErrorException("LoadViewModel", ex))

WhenAnyValue(Function(vm) vm.AgendaItemId) _
  .Where(Function(agendaItemId) agendaItemId > 0) _
  .InvokeCommand(UpdateViewModel)

Private Sub UpdateDetails(agendaItem As AgendaItem)

    _agendaItem = agendaItem

    PrimaryAgendaCategoryId = _agendaItem.AgendaCategory.ParentId

    PrimaryAmount = agendaItem.Amounts.Where(Function(x) x.AmountType = AmountType.Primary).Sum(Function(x) x.Value)
    SecondaryAmount = agendaItem.Amounts.Where(Function(x) x.AmountType = AmountType.Secondary).Sum(Function(x) x.Value)
    LocalMatchAmount = agendaItem.Amounts.Where(Function(x) x.AmountType = AmountType.LocalMatch).Sum(Function(x) x.Value)
    ChangeOrderTotalAmount = agendaItem.Amounts.Where(Function(x) x.AmountType = AmountType.ChangeOrder).Sum(Function(x) x.Value)
    ProjectTotalAmount = agendaItem.Amounts.Sum(Function(x) x.Value)

    Mapper.Map(_agendaItem, Me)

    'TODO fix this attempt at getting save button to refresh when amounts are changed and saved.
    Name = ""
    Name = _agendaItem.Name

End Sub
```

This actually appears to work. The DetailsView is updated with the new values.  Where things fail is when I try update DepartmentContacts.

```
GetDepartmentContacts = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(Function(x) _departmentService.GetDepartmentContactsAsync(AgendaItemId))
GetDepartmentContacts.ToPropertyEx(Me, Function(x) x.DepartmentContacts, New BindingList(Of PersonContactViewModel))
GetDepartmentContacts.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(Sub(ex) Log.ErrorException("GetDepartmentContacts", ex))

WhenAnyValue(Function(vm) vm.AgendaItemId) _
        .Where(Function(id) id > 0) _
        .InvokeCommand(GetDepartmentContacts)
```

The ObservableAsPropertyHelper DepartmentContacts fails to update the View.

If, however, I comment out the invoke of the UpdateViewModel Command, DepartmentContacts is updated without issue.

There must be a better way in ReactiveUI to update my ViewModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the answer with [Combining Commands](https://docs.reactiveui.net/en/user-guide/commands/combining-commands.html).

I think the issue is that I can't use `InvokeCommand` twice on the same observable. `ReactiveCommand.CreateCombined` let me combine the two commands into one command that could be invoked and it would handle invoking both commands assigned to it.

```
UpdateViewModel = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(Function(x) _agendaItemService.FindAsync(AgendaItemId))
UpdateViewModel.SubscribeOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler).Subscribe(Sub(agendaItem) UpdateDetails(agendaItem))
UpdateViewModel.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(Sub(ex) Log.ErrorException("LoadViewModel", ex))

GetDepartmentContacts = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(Function(x) _departmentService.GetDepartmentContactsAsync(AgendaItemId))
GetDepartmentContacts.ToPropertyEx(Me, Function(x) x.DepartmentContacts, New BindingList(Of PersonContactViewModel))
GetDepartmentContacts.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(Sub(ex) Log.ErrorException("GetDepartmentContacts", ex))

RefreshAgendaItemValues = ReactiveCommand.CreateCombined(RefreshViewModel, RefreshDepartmentContacts)

WhenAnyValue(Function(vm) vm.AgendaItemId) _
    .Where(Function(id) id > 0) _
    .InvokeCommand(RefreshAgendaItemValues)
```